# Installation of Lizmap Debian : error with QGIS Server in the action part of the Lizmap plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation, lizmap, debian

We have tried to install Lizmap and QGIS Server on a Debian 11 machine.

The QGIS Server is version 3.28.9 and when tried with the method usr/lib/cgi-bin# /usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi we get the message like in the documentation (with warning about unable to find driver for ECW...) - That part seems ok. I just wonder should we install QGIS Server first and Lizmap after or the other way round?

However when we use the Lizmap plugin in the QGIS project we want to show on the web we have the following error =>

In the first information tab at the bottom where you have a table with Name / Lizmap version / Qgs Server version / Action :
In action it says : 'La réponse ne contient pas Qgis_serveur dans le document JSON'
Which in English means : The answer does not include QGIS Server in the JSON document

Do you have any clue why it is so?
Of course we cannot use any of the other tabs of the plugin.

I am OK with GIS but less comfortable with servers, so a very plain 101 answer would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I just wonder should we install QGIS Server first and Lizmap after or the other way round?

It doesn't matter, it's two different applications, independent at that stage on the installation.

It's only important when you are in the web interface of Lizmap, in the "Administration" panel, you must add the QGIS server URL.

> The answer does not include QGIS Server in the JSON document

We don't know which URL you used, so difficult to answer you. But you should add the URL of the Lizmap Web Client, the one you have in your webbrowser. The URL is written in your administration panel as well.

> I am OK with GIS but less comfortable with servers, so a very plain 101 answer would be fine.

Remember that Lizmap and QGIS server are indeed servers applications. So you need some skills in sysadmin as written in the documentation : https://docs.lizmap.com/current/fr/install/pre_requirements.html#server-administration-knowledge